# Deep copy int array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks, deep-copy

I want to deep copy an array of int. I get an Assertion Error: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) when it goes through the destructor.  Which I've been told is because It's trying to delete something that is not there.  Please let me know if I am on the right track and just need to change something small, or if I am completely lost and don't know it.  I can add more code if needed.

Thanks for the answers.

.h

```
private:
    int* _myArray;
    int _size;
    int _capacity;
```

.cpp

```
MyVector::MyVector()
{
_myArray = new int[2];
_size = 0;
_capacity = 2;
}

MyVector::MyVector(int aSize)
{
_myArray = new int[aSize];
_size = 0;
_capacity = aSize;
}

 MyVector::~MyVector()
 {
if(_myArray != NULL)
{
    delete[] _myArray;
    _myArray = NULL;
}
 }
MyVector::MyVector(const MyVector& mVector)
{
_capacity = mVector._capacity;
_size = mVector._size;

//  if(mVector._myArray)
//  {
//  _myArray = new int[_capacity];

//  copy(mVector._myArray, mVector._myArray+_capacity, _myArray);
//  }
}

  MyVector& MyVector::operator=(MyVector& setterVect)
{
delete [] _myArray;

if(setterVect._myArray)
{
    _myArray = new int[_capacity];

    copy(setterVect._myArray, setterVect._myArray+_capacity, _myArray);
}

return *this;
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize `_myArray` to `NULL` in the default constructor?

Comment: No, I just added the code from my constructors.  I set it to 2.

Comment: A while back I wrote a [blog post](http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/c-dynamic-arrays.html) about dynamic arrays you might find interesting.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure you are following the **[*"Rule of Three"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**.

Apart from copy constructor & destructor You should also provide a copy assignment operator which should do a deep copy of dynamically allocated pointer member.

On a side note, the best solution is to simply drop the dynamically allocated member and use a `std::vector` it saves you all the hassles of manual memory management.

Comment: okay, yeah I realize it'd be better just to use std::vector.  I'm just trying to learn the whole concept of memory allocation and pointers etc. in C++.

Comment: When does the assignment operator get called and when does the copy constructor get called?  I just added an assignment operator.  Is that what I should be doing with it?

Comment: Here's a good [article](http://171.64.64.250/class/cs193d/handouts/14CopyConstructors.pdf) explaining when assignment operator and copy constructor are called.